# Bitwise operators in java

Tags: java, enums, picasso

I have copied the following class from `Picasso's` source code. Actually, I was asking `Picasso` to not to cache images.

Can any one explain to me these two lines

`NO_CACHE(1 << 0),`
`NO_STORE(1 << 1);`

> I know about bitwise operators, I just want to know why we need them
>   here?

They have also suppressed `PointlessBitwiseExpression` warning.

```
/** Designates the policy to use when dealing with memory cache. */
@SuppressWarnings("PointlessBitwiseExpression")
public enum MemoryPolicy {

  /** Skips memory cache lookup when processing a request. */
  NO_CACHE(1 << 0),
  /**
   * Skips storing the final result into memory cache. Useful for one-off requests
   * to avoid evicting other bitmaps from the cache.
   */
  NO_STORE(1 << 1);

  static boolean shouldReadFromMemoryCache(int memoryPolicy) {
    return (memoryPolicy & MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE.index) == 0;
  }

  static boolean shouldWriteToMemoryCache(int memoryPolicy) {
    return (memoryPolicy & MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE.index) == 0;
  }

  final int index;

  private MemoryPolicy(int index) {
    this.index = index;
  }
}
```

Comment: `NO_CACHE` has an `index` value of `1`, `NO_STORE` has an `index` value of `2`.

Comment: They're used for bitmasking in the methods.

Comment: And the kinda strange syntax is a call to the `enums` private constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking why we need them? This code boils down to:

```
NO_CHACHE(1), NO_STORE(2);
```

That's it (and just to be complete here: it those constant declarations simply invoke that private constructor of the enum taking an int value).

Thus, the **answer** to your question is: these shift operations are not needed in any way! They carry no additional value (worse: they seem to confuse readers )

The underlying idea is probably that at some later point some kind of "bit masking" will take place. And you know, when you later think in terms of "bits", somebody had the great idea to "think in bits" when declaring those constants, too.

But in that case, something like

```
NO_CACHE(0b01), NO_STORE(0b10);
```

would pretty much do the job, too. But even that; I would find not helpful. If it at all, I would rather put a javadoc there expressing that those constants are intended to be used as "bitwise flags" later on.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("PointlessBitwiseExpression")` that's why they have suppressed this warning?

Comment: There is a warning for that? If so, most likely. **Pointless**. Priceless!

Comment: That `PointlessBitwiseExpression` might be IDE or static analysis tool specific.

Comment: @mallaudin, it's just a sign to IDEA not to highlight pointless bitwise expressions.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes. I just wanted to figure out why they  needed a pointless bitwise expression here. :)

Comment: **worse: they seem to confuse readers** that's what happened to me!

Comment: I thought so ... I added that sentence for a reason ;-)

Comment: @mallaudin, I would write `1`, `2` and add comments that these constants are the result of `1 << 0`, `1 << 1` respectively rather than adding the IDE-dependent annotation

Comment: So would you say that the use of such an enum (not the bitwise expressions, but the whole enum, designed as a way to allow the user to check for specific flags in a bitmask by calling a method) is a pattern or an anti-pattern?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou As usual: *depends*. But I would rather opt for "anti pattern". You know: Java is meant to be a higher-level OO language. Of course, sometimes you do have to deal with that low-level bitwise stuff; and such enums are one option to hide that from users. But please note: in the end the user is still passing **int** values into those methods. Those have to come from somewhere. So you got an enum that defines non-int policies; but then you have to those weird int-taking methods? Long story short: if I would have to review this ... many many findings ;-)